# Premature ruby exit on RAM intensive program

Tags: ruby, exit

I'm trying to make my Ruby file print every possible IP there can be.

However, it exits prematurely with no error.

```
require 'ipaddress' #Is Installed

RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_FACTOR = 0.1 
#Changes How Much RAM Is Taken Every Request (Tested And Removed, Not The Problem)

#Exits After Here

ip = IPAddress "0.0.0.0/24" #First Range
ip.to('255.255.255.255') #End Range

#Exits Before This Point

out_file = File.new("out.txt", "w") #Create & OpenFile
out_file.puts("#{ip}") #Output Variable To File
out_file.close #Save And Exit
sleep(8)
```

RAM is not a problem, due to having 8Gb worth, and the code exiting before hitting my RAM limit.

Whats causing the program to shutdown?

Comment: 'Whats causing the program to shutdown?' is the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track but you should use the gem in a slightly different way:

```
ip = IPAddress "0.0.0.0/0"

File.open("out.txt", "w") do |file|
  ip.each do |ip_address|
    file.puts ip_address
  end
end

sleep(8)
```

This used a finite (and reasonable) amount of RAM on my laptop when I tested it. However, I did not write out to a file, just to the console. Hopefully you are prepared to deal with the size of file this will produce.

Comment: I have 250Gb. lets hope thats enough.

Comment: Welp. Im getting a terabyte drive.